# Variáveis e estrutura de controle de fluxo if no Java

Tags: java

O pretendido é que o utilizador introduza 3 números e que no fim apareça a frase "*O maior valor é X o valor do meio é Y e o menor valor é Z*". Em que X, Y e Z são os números introduzidos. **Só posso fazer com `if`s.** Estou a testar no cmd.

Como poderia fazer o código abaixo **somente com `if`s** de forma mais abreviada?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P02IfsTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduza 3 números: ");

        int scan1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int scan2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int scan3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        int menor = 0;
        int meio = 0; 
        int maior = 0;

        if(scan1 > scan2 && scan1 > scan3 && scan2 > scan3) {
            maior = scan1;
            meio = scan2;
            menor = scan3;
        }
        if(scan1 > scan2 && scan1 > scan3 && scan3 > scan2) {
            maior = scan1;
            meio = scan3;
            menor = scan2;
        }
        if(scan2 > scan1 && scan2 > scan3 && scan1 > scan3) {    
            maior = scan2;
            meio = scan1;
            menor = scan3;
        }
        if(scan2 > scan1 && scan2 > scan3 && scan1 < scan3) {
            maior = scan2;
            meio = scan3;
            menor = scan1;
        }
        if(scan3 > scan1 && scan3 > scan2 && scan1 > scan2) {
            maior = scan3;
            meio = scan1;
            menor = scan2;
        }
        if(scan3 > scan1 && scan3 > scan2 && scan1 < scan2) {
            maior = scan3;
            meio = scan2;
            menor = scan1;
        }
        System.out.println("O maior valor é " + maior + " o valor do meio é " + meio + " e o menor valor é " + menor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73916/discussion-on-question-by-catarina-mota-variaveis-e-estrutura-de-controle-de-flu)

Answer (score 1):

O problema que o compilador está mostrando no terminal

02IfsTest.java:47: error: variable maior might not have been initialized System.out.println("O maior valor Ú " + maior + " o valor do meio Ú " + meio + " e o menor valor Ú " + menor);

é que voce nao inicializou as variáveis maior, meio e menor.

o Correto a fazer seria :

```
int menor = 0;
int meio = 0;
int maior = 0;
```

O compilador não consegue definir qual o valor default das suas variáveis pelo motivo delas estarem declaradas dentro do método main que é um método estático.

Caso queira voce também pode declarar suas variáveis como estáticas fora do método.

```
public class Main {

static int menor;
static int meio;
static int maior;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
.....
```

Comment: Já resolvi o bug. Obrigada.

Comment: Teria que fazer um if para, por exemplo, scan1 ser igual a scan2?

Comment: Nao da para fazer isto de forma mais abreviada so com ifs?

Comment: Gustavo, creio que o certo não seja exatamente inicializar com o valor padrão 0. Ele não retornaria mais erro de compilação, mas "conceitualmente" poderia ter valores errados. O correto seria garantir que o código passará por um dos branches de execução. E isso se faria usando os `elses` para executar o "outro lado" apenas caso a condição não seja satisfeita

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim entendo a sua questão, como disse na resposta apenas tentei explicar o erro apresentado pelo compilador e o porque do erro, pois assim ela entenderia o real motivo daquele erro apresentado.

Comment: @GustavodeSouza entendi seu ponto agora. Na leitura rápida eu não havia entendido que era essa a intenção, nem me apaguei do jeito que você falou

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com três `if`s assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P02IfsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduza 3 números: ");

        int scan1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int scan2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        int scan3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        int menor = scan1, meio = scan2, maior = scan3;

        if (menor > meio) {
            int x = menor;
            menor = meio;
            meio = x;
        }

        if (menor > maior) {
            int x = menor;
            menor = maior;
            maior = x;
        }

        if (meio > maior) {
            int x = meio;
            meio = maior;
            maior = x;
        }

        System.out.println("O maior valor é " + maior
                + " o valor do meio é " + meio
                + " e o menor valor é " + menor);
    }
}
```

A ideia é a seguinte:

1. Inicialmente, coloque os valores `menor`, `meio` e `maior` como os valores dados, em qualquer ordem.
2. Verifique se o valor do `menor` é de fato menor que o valor inicial do `meio` e que o do `maior` e troque-os se não for. Isso vai garantir que a variável `menor` ficará com o menor dos três valores. Isso daqui dá para se fazer com dois `if`s.
3. Verifique se o valor do `meio` e do `maior` estão invertidos e troque-os se for o caso.

Comment: Mas assim estou a assumir que o sca1 é o menor, etc

Comment: E a sintaxe nao esta a mais correta

Comment: @CatarinaMota Sim, está correto. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ljNq8q)

Comment: @CatarinaMota Você assume ***apenas inicialmente*** que o `scan1` é o menor. Os `if`s servem exatamente para corrigir essa presunção inicial caso ela seja falsa.